# Scatterplot axis labels are wrong when plotting dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I am trying to do a scatter plot of 2 time series data - the data is stored in a data frame. The background of the image is quite grainy and axis labels are not visible when I do:

```
ggplot(data=dat,aes(x,y))+geom_point()
```

With below, I get only dark vertical lines:

```
plot(dat$x,dat$y)
```

`plot()` and `ggplot()` did work after applying `as.numeric()` to the data(as below) **but the axis labels are indices[1,2,...] and not the range of actual values.**

```
plot(as.numeric(dat$x),as.numeric(dat$y))
ggplot(data=dat,aes(as.numeric(x),as.numeric(y)))+geom_point()
```

I cannot post the images here as I am new to this forum.

Comment: Not reproducible: we need the results of `summary(dat)` or `str(dat)` at the very least. (I'm guessing that `x` got turned into a factor; try `as.numeric(as.character(dat$x))` ...) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm going to guess that you forgot to turn the variable into a date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the data was getting converted into factor while converting from matrix to data.frame. Below code fixed it.

```
data.frame(mydata,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```